# Can I use gloss on Android?

Tags: android, haskell, opengl-es, gloss

[Gloss](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/gloss) is a Haskell library for OpenGL games and simulations. Android seems to support OpenGL.

Is there a way to run a library based on Gloss on an Android device?

Comment: Can you run Haskell and glfw on Android?

Comment: @ThomasM.DuBuisson sure, see [this](https://github.com/neurocyte/android-haskell-activity) for example, or [this Docker image](https://github.com/sseefried/docker-build-ghc-android)

Comment: @Cactus I'm well aware of the Android GHC work, the point was that this question can be broken down into components that can be more easily searched or individually answered.  For example, Gloss has two backends so while GLFW does not appear to be a good option some people have pushed GLUT on android a little.  Either way, so much is hard-coded in the concept of operations (full screen and a keyboard interface) that I personally wouldn't look to use Gloss on Android... but if someone makes it painless then yay!